# copy tree structure in MySql and update ids

Tags: mysql

I have below structure of tables

- table_a

  - table_b

    - table_c

table_c has external keys in table_b and table_b in table_a, all tables has relation one to many (one parent)
all tables have columnt environment_id

I have to copy structure for 2 rows from table_a and past to the same table with other environment_id

if I run script

```
    insert into table_a (environment_id, text, is_default, type)
(select -1001, text, is_default, type
    from table_a
    where environment_id = -1005);

insert into table_b
    (environment_id, a_id, ordinal, text, level)
     (select -1001, 
             (select formulaid from table_a where environment_id = -1001 and text = 
                          (select text from table_a where formulaid = a_id))
             ordinal, text, level);



insert into table_c
    (environment_id, b_id, languageid, translation)
    (select -1001, (select id from table_b
                    where environment_id = -1001 and text = (select text from table_b 
                                    where environment_id = -1005 and text = (
                                        select text from table_b where id = b_id))), 
            languageid, translation);
```

I will receive expected result for 1st table, but how to manage with rest?
I want to new rows from table_b point new rows from table_a, same with table_c and table_b.

Comment: Provide a sample as complete CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts for starting data (or create online fiddle) and desired final data state as formatted table.

Comment: *I will receive expected result for 1st table, but how to manage with rest?* Use 2 copies of source tables - first for retrieve link and second for to retrieve new reference value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join same table with

```
select * from table_a first left join table_a second
on first.text = second.text
```

and get new id by comparing text field